# Change Setting for PushNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification

i am using push notification in my app.
i want to on/off push notfication service from switch in my app.

like from my app if i make pushnotification off , then in general setting it will off automatically.

Comment: When you say PushNotification, I hope you don't mean a `UILocalNotification`..

Comment: No , i am using Push Notification.

Answer (score 1):

you can't turned it off in the general settings from your app .. how ever maybe you could do it on another way .. please check my answer here [how do I disregard push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9968628/705559)

Comment: from setting in my device , i can make notification on/off for particular app, then i can't handel it from my app ?

Comment: i think , i can handle twitter (iOS - 5 )by it , i can get username by it so why push notification is not possible ?

Comment: its a different thing for the twitter and push notification .. apple is not allow you to change the general settings from your app